# Electron loadURL incorrectly force HTTPS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, https, electron

Electron tries to load the URL with HTTPS protocol, but what I load is explicitly HTTP.
Webpack loads correctly at the HTTP address, so it should be an Electrum problem.

`mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:8080/index.html'))`

```
[3396:0330/104324.454:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(995)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
[3396:0330/104324.530:ERROR:ssl_client_socket_impl.cc(995)] handshake failed; returned -1, SSL error code 1, net_error -107
(node:6116) electron: Failed to load URL: https://localhost:8080/index.html with error: ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

```
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Project is running at:
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Loopback: http://localhost:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] On Your Network (IPv4): http://192.168.0.3:8080/
<i> [webpack-dev-server] Content not from webpack is served from 'C:\gestionalefp_client\public' directory
<i> [webpack-dev-server] 404s will fallback to '/index.html'
```

Answer (score 1):

By default a `BrowserWindow` has web security enabled. This means it will try to access any URL securely. Init your `BrowserWindow` like this:

```
let mainView = new BrowserWindow({
  ...
  webPreferences: {
    allowDisplayingInsecureContent: true,
    allowRunningInsecureContent: true
  }
});
```

and in `main.js`

```
app.commandLine.appendSwitch('ignore-certificate-errors');
```

Also verify that your web server isn't sending any HSTS headers.

Comment: It is not working for me

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by enabling https on webpack config

```
devServer: { https: true }
```